# XML/XSLT - Unable to pick up multiple nodes from XML document

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I'm very new to XSLT and am trying to convert the following XML file to a comma separated list:

```
<town>Some Town</town>
<city>Some City</city>
```

With the following XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="town"/>,
        <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following error when using [this online transformer](http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php):

```
Error:DOMDocument::loadXML() [<a href='domdocument.loadxml'>domdocument.loadxml</a>]: Extra content at the end of the document in Entity, line: 3
```

Although, if I remove the `<city>Some City</city>` element from the input file, then my output works and I get the following:

```
Some Town,
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is:

```
Some Town,Some City
```

I also have a scenario where the `<city>` element may not appear and the XML file will only contain a `<town>` - should my XSLT file still work in this scenario? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should enclose your xml file in a `root` tag.

The reason why it's working if you remove the `<city>Some City</city>` element from the input file is because it treats `<town>` as the root.

Comment: Thanks @Joel. Enclosing in a root tag has solved the problem.